# How can I enable remote connections for MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a MariaDB instance running with proper users set up. My `my.cnf` looks like this:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

symbolic-links=0

bind-address    = 0.0.0.0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

I'm trying to connect to this DB from Windows MySQL Workbench as root and am getting

> Unable to connect to MYSQL server on `<servername>`

When I run `netstat -aonp | grep 3306` on my server I get:

`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12793/mysqld         off (0.00/0/0)`

All looks to be running just fine and my bind-address is set to all 0's.

What could I possibly be missing here?

Comment: Is the server behind a firewall or NAT? You may need to open some ports.

Comment: You have to change the bind address to the actual IP address or it will only listen for local connections.

Comment: @flip this is a server. I'd want more than one IP to be able to access.. what is the `actual IP` you are suggesting?

Comment: @aynber It's not behind any additional firewalls that I know of. I'm trying to access from within

Comment: What's the full error message?

Comment: @aynber "Failed to Connect to MySQL at (server):3306 with user root. Can't connect to MYSQL server on (server) (10060)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this was a new VM, `FirewallD` was not running.

I needed to start `FirewallD` and add `3306/tcp` to it:

`firewall-cmd --add-port=3306/tcp`

`firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=3306/tcp`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's the issue with permission

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'*' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```